# Outside of the DCAU, does Post-Crisis/Pre- New 52 Superman have a "super mobile", ship or other form of protective transport?

Tags: superman, canon, vehicles, transportation

In various media, we have seen Superman *occasionally* use a mechanical form of transport, more for its anti-Kryptonite protective properties than for travel. Most instances of this have been **pre-Crisis** however. Most notable would be the late 70s to 80s "Super Powers team" cartoon era. The only other detailed reference to a multi-use vehicle would be in the animated series, where Clark was able to repurpose the ship that brought him from Krypton into a functional transport.

I was wondering if there are any instances in the Post-Crisis comics where he has some special signature vehicle he uses and what it or they may look like?

Answer (score 3):

While the Super-Mobile is primarily a pre-Crisis device, it's made a couple (semi-whimsical) appearances post-crisis, mainly as meta in-jokes

[From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermobile) -

> A few different versions of the Supermobile are seen protecting a
>   futuristic Ivy Town in All-New Atom #8. The classic design of the
>   vehicle can also be seen atop the sign of Funky Flashman's used
>   automobile dealership (which also contains a lot full of Batmobiles
>   from various media) in the fifth chapter of the Doctor Thirteen serial
>   "Architecture and Morality" in Tales of the Unexpected #5.

Comment: Thanks, man. can you provide some scans of those?